# store users in one table or multiple table Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel

we are creating an e-learning website with Laravel, and we have multiple users (student, instructor, admin) should we store them in one table (users) or each user with own table.

I want to know if there is a convention

Comment: How you separate the user types is up to you. I've seen multiple projects where all users were stored in a single table with boolean flags for admin/staff. I've also seen projects where administrators were stored separate to users.
I was also brought into a project to convert a "user has admin" flag system into a "user has [x] role", where [x] would relate to a roles/permissions table for granular site accesses.
Authenticate and authorize as desired!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no set in stone rule, it is totally up to you. But from what I see in most Laravel projects, and what I do in my projects as well, to make it easier to read/troubleshoot you use a single "users" table and make a "profile" or "profile_type" column to determine which one are they attached to.